# VBA Excel --> PWP - Blank when copy

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a little issue with my macro. I know it's not the perfect one but at least it works.

The only thing is that when I go step by step it is going perfectly but when I run it all the new slides are blank.

Do you have an idea how to improve that ?

```
Sub paste_toPPT()

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim pptApp As Object
Dim pptPres As Object
Dim myRange As Excel.Range
Dim path As String
Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim saveName As String
Dim image As Object
Dim IDe As String
Dim count As Integer

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
On Error Resume Next
'Is PowerPoint already opened?
Set pptApp = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")
'Clear the error between errors
Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
If pptApp Is Nothing Then Set pptApp = CreateObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")
'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Open template
DestinationPPT = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ID Card\Kpi ID.pptx"
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

Windows("KPI List - P2P KPI.xlsm").Activate
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("KPI List").Range("E:E")) - 1

For i = 8 To count
    Worksheets("KPI List").Select
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("KPI List").Select
    IDe = Worksheets("KPI List").Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 5))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ID").Range("F4:F4") = IDe
    'Set the range to copy
    Windows("KPI List - P2P KPI.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("ID").Select
    Worksheets("ID").Shapes.Range(Array("Group 57")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Add slide & Paste data

    pptPres.Windows(1).Activate
    Set mySlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, 12)
    mySlide.Select
    pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
Next i

pptPres.SaveAs DestinationPPT

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code as comments:

```
Sub paste_toPPT()

Dim pptApp As Object
Dim pptPres As Object
Dim myRange As Excel.Range
Dim path As String
Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim saveName As String
Dim image As Object
Dim IDe As String
Dim count As Integer

' added 2 worksheet objects
Dim wsKPI As Worksheet
Dim wsID As Worksheet

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
On Error Resume Next
'Is PowerPoint already opened?
Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
'Clear the error between errors
Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
If pptApp Is Nothing Then Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Open template
DestinationPPT = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ID Card\Kpi ID.pptx"
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

' no need to Activate the workbook first, just set the worksheet objects
Set wsKPI = Workbooks("KPI List - P2P KPI.xlsm").Sheets("KPI List")
Set wsID = Workbooks("KPI List - P2P KPI.xlsm").Sheets("ID")

count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("E:E")) - 1

For i = 8 To count
    IDe = wsKPI.Range(wsKPI.Cells(i, 5), wsKPI.Cells(i, 5))
    wsID.Range("F4:F4") = IDe

    ' first add the slide , later do the copy>>paste as close as can be
    Set mySlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, 12)

    ' Set the range to copy (no need to Select first)
    wsID.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 57")).Copy

    mySlide.Select
    pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
Next i

pptPres.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("E:E")) - 1  should be
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsKPI.Range("E:E")) - 1
I think